# SQL. Incorrect syntax near the keyword

Tags: c#, sql, syntax

How can i fix these errors?

[image]
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Adatbázis_kezelés
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Szabolcs\Documents\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            String query = "insert into Table (id,Name,Fname,Age,Gender,Addres) VALUES('"+textBox1.Text+ "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "')";
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("INSTERTION SUCCESSFULLY !!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't post the images. And it would be better to post the error messages as text (so they are searchable).

Comment: And your code is open to [**SQL injections**](https://www.bobby-tables.com/). And if for example your `id` column is numeric then the single quotes around the first parameter are wrong.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: Errors messages are text, for future reference, it is customary to put the message in the question as text. As for the error, you have a syntax error in your sql which is very common when you build sql by concatenating strings. Using parameters not only protects against sql injection, it helps avoid syntax errors as well.

Comment: Escape `table`: `insert into [Table] ... `

Comment: You should not name your table `Table`, because `Table` is a reserved keyword in SQL. To make this code work at least, escape that name like `insert into [Table]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Table` is a reserved word in SQL you should wrap it into brackets.

```
INSERT INTO [Table] ...
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, its working. Have a nice day :D